# How do I make autopep8 allow a comment at the end of a line?

Tags: python, formatting, formatter, autopep8

I'm trying to format my code with autopep8 (because this appears to be the default one in VSCode). But there is a problem with it:

I am using a lib that doesn't care about typing, so I need to suffix some lines with `# type:ignore` to make the linter ignore that particular file. But when formatting (with autopep8) the formatter moves the comment to the line above. Then my linter doesn't ignore the line like it should.

So with e.g. this code:

```py
somevar = dumblib.foobar() #type:ignore
```

I hit Shift+Alt+F to format, and then the code is formatted to this:

```py
# type:ignore
somevar = dumblib.foobar()
```

And then, the linter complains that the type of "somevar" is unknonwn.

How can I prevent autopep8 from moving the comment during a reformat?

Answer (score 1):

It's a relatively old question but in case others also struggle with this, I will leave a solution that helped me.

The autopep8 rule that is responsible for moving comments above the code line is nothing but a `max-line-length`. I was able to fix this by increasing the maximum line length. To do this I created a configuration file in my project (.pep8) and configured vscode to use it (in the autopep8 extension settings).

Configuration file contents:

```yaml
[pep8]
max-line-length = 160
```

Comment: How did you configure vscode to use the .pep8 config file that you created?